# multiple div hover effect on one page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, hover

So I found this script on a different post on here and have changed it to fit my style/site but its only working for 1 div. I would like to use it on multiple divs on the same page though but when I duplicate the divs only 1 of them works. Should it be able to work as all divs are named the same or do I have to name each div different, do separate css for each div AND separate script for each div? im trying to avoid having to add all that coding if not needed as I am setting it up to pull from posts and auto appear with out having to go in and edit coding for it.

this is the coding i am using right now. The one on the left works but any additional one i ad doesn't work when i hover over it.

HTML

```
<div id="client" style="float:left;">
<div id="client_slider">
    <p>content...</p>
</div>
</div>

<div id="client" style="float:left;">
<div id="client_slider">
    <p>content...</p>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#client {
position: relative;
overflow:hidden;
background-color:#ffff00;
width: 320px;
height: 320px;
}
#client_slider {
width: 320px;
height: 320px;
bottom: -320px;
right: 0px;
background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
position: absolute;
color:#fff;
}
```

SCRIPT

```
$(function () {
$('#client').on("mouseenter", function () {
    $("#client_slider").animate({
        "bottom": "-240px"
    }, "slow");
}).on("mouseleave", function () {
    $("#client_slider").animate({
        "bottom": "-320px"
    }, "fast");
});
});
```

Sample link

http://jsfiddle.net/4yhKP/

Comment: Multiple div with same id not allowed in HTML.

Comment: Multiple *anything* with the same `id` is not allowed ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IDs must be unique, if you want multiple, use classes instead. You'll also need to change the jQuery code:

```
$(function () {
    $('.client').on("mouseenter", function () {
        $(this).children(".client_slider").animate({
            "bottom": "-240px"
        }, "slow");
    }).on("mouseleave", function () {
        $(this).children(".client_slider").animate({
            "bottom": "-320px"
        }, "fast");
    });
});
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4yhKP/6/)

Answer (score 1):

Use `class` instead of `id`.

ID must be unique

[**Fidlle DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/4yhKP/3/)

```
$(function () {
    $('.client').on("mouseenter", function () {
        $(".client_slider").animate({
            "bottom": "-240px"
        }, "slow");
    }).on("mouseleave", function () {
        $(".client_slider").animate({
            "bottom": "-320px"
        }, "fast");
    });
});
```

Read [Two HTML elements with same id attribute: How bad is it really?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/127178/two-html-elements-with-same-id-attribute-how-bad-is-it-really)

Answer (score 0):

### Working [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sarathsprakash/4yhKP/17/)

You can have only unique id attribute for elements.

### html

```
<div class="client" style="float:left;">
    <div class="client_slider">
        <p>content...</p>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="client" style="float:left;">
    <div class="client_slider">
        <p>content...</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

### css

```
.client {
    position: relative;
    overflow:hidden;
    background-color:#ffff00;
    width: 320px;
    height: 320px;
}
.client_slider {
    width: 320px;
    height: 320px;
    bottom: -320px;
    right: 0px;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
    position: absolute;
    color:#fff;
}
```

### code

```
$(function () {
    $('.client').on("mouseenter", function () {
        $(this).find(".client_slider").animate({
            "bottom": "-240px"
        }, "slow");
    }).on("mouseleave", function () {
        $(this).find(".client_slider").animate({
            "bottom": "-320px"
        }, "fast");
    });
});
```

Hope this helps, Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It's attached to an ID not a class.

Switch it to be a class instead and it will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

It is not happening because you have attached same `id` to divs.
`id` must be unique.

Change it to class.

Code:

```
$(function () {
    $('.client').on("mouseenter", function () {
        var th = $(this);
        $(th).find(".client_slider").animate({
            "bottom": "-240px"
        }, "slow");
    }).on("mouseleave", function () {
        var th = $(this);
        $(th).find(".client_slider").animate({
            "bottom": "-320px"
        }, "fast");
    });
});
```

[Updated fiddle here.](http://jsfiddle.net/4yhKP/11/)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are calling the mouseenter function on a id. Replace this code with your calling function and it will work. I would say that you change your id:clients to a class.

```
  $(function () {
        $('div').on("mouseenter", function () {
            $(this).children('div').animate({
                "bottom": "-240px"
            }, "slow");
        }).on("mouseleave", function () {
           $(this).find('div').animate({
                "bottom": "-320px"
            }, "fast");
        });
    });
```